# How to handle inclusive -21, -103 Invalid value: Not in range RangeError in Dart?

Tags: error-handling, socket.io, dart, range, aqueduct

I have socket app that was working over a year. One user data seems out of range. User keep getting  inclusive -21, -103 Invalid value: Not in range RangeError.

**Error String:** 
RangeError (length): Invalid value: Not in range 0..576460752303423487, inclusive: -103

How to handle inclusive -21, -103 Invalid value: Not in range RangeError in Dart?

```
try {
  String _reply = “”;

    socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.1.10’, 8080);
    socket.write('Server__Query__Part\r\n');

    socket.handleError((data) {
      print(data);
    }

    await for (var data in socket) {
      _reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
      socket.close();
      socket.destroy();
    }
  } 
} catch (error, StackTrace trace) {
  print(error);
}
```

**StackTrace current:**

```
-- Aqueduct CLI Version: 3.1.0+1
-- Aqueduct project version: 3.1.0+1
-- Preparing...
-- Starting application 'ntmsapi/ntmsapi'
    Channel: NtmsapiChannel
    Config: /home/capital/.urcs/ntms/ntmsapi/config.yaml
    Port: 8888
[INFO] aqueduct: Server aqueduct/1 started.  
[INFO] aqueduct: Server aqueduct/2 started.  

=====================================================================
RangeError (length): Invalid value: Not in range 0..576460752303423487, inclusive: -197
=====================================================================
=====================================================================
#0      new _List (dart:core/runtime/libarray.dart)
#1      List._allocateData (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:240:16)
#2      List._shrink (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:263:19)
#3      List.length= (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:132:7)
#4      pkcs7Unpad (package:tripledes/src/utils.dart:68:8)
#5      BaseEngine.process (package:tripledes/src/engine.dart:77:7)
#6      BlockCipher.decodeB64 (package:tripledes/tripledes.dart:37:20)
#7      getPrivate (package:ntmsapi/util/ntmsGetPrivate.dart:8:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      NtmsApiController.handle (package:ntmsapi/controller/ntmsapi_controller.dart:36:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      Controller.receive (package:aqueduct/src/http/controller.dart:174:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     Controller.receive (package:aqueduct/src/http/controller.dart:206:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     Router.receive (package:aqueduct/src/http/router.dart:139:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#15     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:132:11)
#16     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:232:10)
#17     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:164:13)
#18     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#19     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#20     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#21     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:763:19)
#22     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:639:7)
#23     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:585:5)
#24     _HttpServer._handleRequest (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2660:19)
#25     new _HttpConnection.<anonymous closure> (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2418:19)
#26     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#27     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#28     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#29     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:763:19)
#30     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:639:7)
#31     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:585:5)
#32     _HttpParser._headersEnd (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:372:19)
#33     _HttpParser._doParse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:701:15)
#34     _HttpParser._parse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:318:7)
#35     _HttpParser._onData (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:810:5)
#36     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#37     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#38     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#39     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:763:19)
#40     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:639:7)
#41     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:585:5)
#42     _Socket._onData (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:1721:41)
#43     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#44     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#45     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#46     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:763:19)
#47     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:639:7)
#48     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:585:5)
#49     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:1283:33)
#50     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:826:14)
#51     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#52     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#53     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#54     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)

=====================================================================
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Hi Günter, this was working last 6 months, I will get more detail now

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I update my question. I use StackTrace current to get the error

Comment: Did you update to Dart 2 recently?

Comment: Please add the output of `dart --version`.

Comment: When new update comes I allow to update machine. And I guess it update dart as well. The dart versin is:  Dart VM version: 2.1.0 (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"

Comment: Same problem with "Dart SDK version: 2.10.5 (stable) (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64""